# Orange filter in python script

Tags: orange

how to filter data table  in Orange3's Python Script widget?

What i want to do :

```
out_data = in_data //that the column "number" value is below 42
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are working with an Orange.data.Table. [The tutorial](https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/data-mining-library/) recommends something like this:

```
out_data = Orange.data.Table(in_data.domain,
                             [d for d in in_data if d["number"] < 42.0])
```

Building a list of valid indices and then filtering might be simpler:

```
sel = [i for i, d in enumerate(in_data) if d["number"] < 42.0]
out_data = in_data[sel]
```